# Steps $1$ and $3$ of the proof of the Second Existence Theorem for weak solutions of elliptic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I'm studying by myself PDE by the Evans' book and I'm trying understand the Second Existence Theorem for weak solutions of elliptic equations and I'm trying understand the steps $1$ and $3$ of the proof ([this topic has an image with the theorem and the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240038/a-question-regarding-the-proof-of-the-second-existence-theorem-for-weak-solution)), but there are two points that I didn't understand:

1) Why $(13)$ is true? I think it is used the [Lax-Milgram Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069836/a-possible-redundant-step-in-evanss-proof-of-the-lax-milgram-theorem), but I don't sure because $u$ would be in $U$ and not in $H^1_0(U)$, right? Because $g \in L^2(U)$ and $u$ must be an element of the domain of $g$ by the Lax-Milgram Theorem.

2) How obtain $|| Kg ||_{H^1_0(U)} \leq C ||g||_{L^2(U)}$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are correct that you can verify this via Lax-Milgram lemma. I think you have confused $g$ and the linear functional $H^1_0(U)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $v\mapsto (g,v)$. The domain of that operator is $H^1_0(U)$, not $U$. $U$ is the domain of the functions $u,v,g,f$.
2. It tells you to refer back to a previous section, which I believe introduces the trace operator, which relates a function to its boundary values and establishes the bound you mention

Comment: 1. This makes more sense now, thanks!

2. Can you give more details please? There 
is the Trace Theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608958/some-doubts-on-the-trace-theorem), but I can't see how this is related to my doubt.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the theorem the first time I answered. The statement above the inequality you are referring to is proving that $K$ is bounded. Dividing both sides of that statement by $\|u\|^2_{H_0^1(U)}$ and then letting $u=g$ and dividing by $\beta$ gives you the desired inequality.

Comment: I think you want to say "observe that $u = \frac{Kg}{\gamma}$ by $(14)$ and $(18)$" and not "letting $u = g$", right?